# $\exists f\in C^1$ such that $f(0)=0,\;f(x)>0\;\forall x>0$, but $f'\leq0$ for points near zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The question is about the existence of a function $f:[0,+\infty),$ with $f\in C^1\left([0,+\infty)\right)$ such that

$$f(0)=0,\quad f(x)>0,\;\forall x>0,$$

and there is a strictly decreasing sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset[0,1)$ with $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0$ such that

$$f'(x_n)\leq0,\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

The exercise was about proving that such $f$ doesn't exist... but I failed in all my attempts.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Intuitively, if you choose a $x_n$ that is arbitrarily close to zero, and the slope there is negative, the function is dropping there. With $f(0)=0$, we can see the function starts from zero and is dropping. However, this is forbidden by $f(x)>0$. Thus, such function does not exist.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ fulfills all your criterias…

Comment: @Gono The derivative has to be negative near zero.

Comment: @Szeto No, the derivative has to be non-negative. And $f'(0) = 0 \le 0$

Comment: @Gono What $\{x_n\}$ would be suitable?

Comment: $x_n \equiv 0$…

Comment: @Gono That’s a problem...one more condition is needed for the non-existence of function(which is the purpose of the exercise): the sequence is not ‘constant’.

Comment: OFC if you add randomly new conditions to the question the answer won't be suitable. But this is not contained in the question… if it is the questioner should edit the question.

Comment: @Szeto I understand what you say, but when I want to proof that I don't have any success. What I want is to know how to proof that, if it is really a truth.

Comment: @Fernando But now it is not a truth. You can’t prove it.

Comment: The sequence can be considered strictly decreasing, I'm going to edit that.

Comment: @Szeto I mean, that the not existence it is truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such function **does** exist. Consider 
$$f(x):=x^3(2+\sin(1/x))$$
extended by continuity at $x=0$ (see a plot at [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot(x%5E3*(2%2Bsin(1%2Fx)),x%3D0..0.01))).

We have that $f\in C^1\left([0,+\infty)\right)$, $f(0)=0$, and $f(x)>0$ for  $x>0$. Moreover, there is a strictly decreasing positive sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ such that $x_n\to 0^+$ and $f'(x_n)<0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can find non-trivial counter-examples for this. For every $n$, let $f_n:[1/(2n),1/(2n-1)]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that satisfies:

- $supp(f_n)\subseteq (1/(2n),1/(2n-1))$;
- $f_n'(x)<-2$ for some $x$;
- $\max_x |f_n(x)|<1/(2n)$

You can construct these functions by playing around with mollifiers and something like $e^{-1/(x^2)}$. You can see mollifiers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

The general idea is that it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yJjh.png).

Now patch up all these functions: Let $g$ be equal to $f_n$ on each interval $[1/(2n),1/(2n-1)]$, and 0 everywhere else. The function $f(x)=g(x)+x$ has the properties you want and $f'(x_n)<-1$ for a sequence of point $x_n\in[1/(2n),1/(2n-1)]$

---

EDIT: This can be seen as a soft version of  [Robert Z's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2826174/160185)

Answer (score 2):

Set
$$
f(x)=x^{5/2}\left(2+\sin\Big(\frac1x\Big)\right)
$$
Then

a. $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$, for all $x>0$.

b. $f'(x)=\frac{5}{2}x^{3/2}\left(2+\sin\Big(\frac1x\Big)\right)-x^{1/2}\cos\Big(\frac1x\Big)$, so for $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi}\to 0^+$ we have
$$
f'(x_n)=\frac{5}{2}(2\pi n)^{-3/2}\big(2+\sin(2n\pi)\big)-(2n\pi)^{-1/2}\cos(2n\pi)=5(2\pi n)^{-3/2}-(2\pi n)^{-1/2} \\ = (2\pi n)^{-1/2}\left(\frac{5}{2\pi n}-1\right).
$$
Observe that 
$$
f'(x_n)<0
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: But the derivative it is not continuous in zero...

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis Your function is NOT $C^1\left([0,+\infty)\right)$. This is the reason why I put a $x^3$.

Comment: @Fernando: I have modified $f$ to be $C^1$ in $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a $C^\infty$ example with this property:

$$f(x) = e^{-1/x}(2+ \sin(1/x^2)),\,\, x> 0,$$

$f(0)=0.$ Here you can check $f'(1/\sqrt {2n\pi})<0$ for $n=1,2,\dots$

However, there is no real analytic example with this property.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take $f(x) = x^2, x_n \equiv 0$ and you are done.

edit: This answer was for a former version of this question. Now it's wrong obviously

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, but I was looking for the other answers